# Formula for calculating the monthly payment for a Personal Contract Purchase

Tags: loans, interest-rate, calculation, apr

How can I calculate the monthly payment for a PCP (Personal Contract Purchase) when given the variables below?

1. 'Amount to be financed' - finance amount
2. APR (annual percentage rate - %)
3. Length of finance (duration)
4. Final Payment (GMFV / balloon payment)

Need to get a formula to calculate this.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to calculate from APR? @ChrisDegnen

Comment: Could you please advise how to calculate monthly payment if balloon is not paid in monthly?

https://www.carwow.co.uk/pcp-calculator   I'm using this site to calculate.  @ChrisDegnen

Comment: M = (R (B - L (1 + R)^N))/(1 - (1 + R)^N)
This one, right? @ChrisDegnen

Also, Here R=APR/12, Right?

Comment: For United Kingdom?

Comment: I've edited my question and added an image reference(Contains the values).
@ChrisDegnen

Comment: `M = (R (B - L (1 + R)^N))/(1 - (1 + R)^N)` is for a different calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With

s = principal
n = no. periods
m = periodic payment
r = periodic rate
b = balloon
```

where the balloon is paid *at the same time* as the final payment in month *n*

[image: eq]

The present value of the principal is equated to the net present values of the payments; then the [summation is converted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o03Xs.png) to a closed-form expression by induction.

```
∴ s = (m - m (1 + r)^-n)/r + b/(1 + r)^n

∴ m = (r ((1 + r)^n s - b))/((1 + r)^n - 1)
```

Assuming the dealer contribution is deducted from the initial amount.

```
s = 20000 - 2000 - 1000
b = 1000
r = (1 + 7/100)^(1/12) - 1
n = 36

∴ m = (r ((1 + r)^n s - b))/((1 + r)^n - 1) = 498.12
```

or calculating with APR as a nominal rate compounded monthly

```
s = 20000 - 2000 - 1000
b = 1000
r = 7/100/12
n = 36

∴ m = (r ((1 + r)^n s - b))/((1 + r)^n - 1) = 499.87
```

Looks like the website is using nominal rates.  However, UK uses effective rates.

Comment: I think the following method is correct for my case.

s = 20000 - 2000 - 1000
b = 1000
r = (1 + 7/100)^(1/12) - 1
n = 36

∴ m = (r ((1 + r)^n s - b))/((1 + r)^n - 1) = 498.12

Comment: r = (1 + 7/100)^(1/12) - 1

Comment: That is correct for the UK where APR is advertised as the [effective rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation).